# Error 504 gateway time-out

Tags: yii2

I have a problem with download excel file from site. I use kartik\export\ExportMenu; I add into view in script this :

```
 <?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
$gridColumns = [
    'order_number',
    [
```

But it doesnt help. How could I fixed it?

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new OrderSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: you have time-out after 5 minutes?   . how much is long the excel files? or the related  dataProvider?

Answer (score 1):

There are three configurations that can help in case of timeouts but it's not guaranteed.

Options to set in `ExportMenu` widget configuration:

1. [Large Files Linking](http://demos.krajee.com/export-demo#large-files-link)

   ```
   'stream' => false
   ```
2. [Large Files Streaming](http://demos.krajee.com/export-demo#large-files-stream)

   ```
   'stream' => false, // this will automatically save the file to a folder on web server
   'streamAfterSave' => true, // this will stream the file to browser after its saved on the web folder 
   'deleteAfterSave' => true, // this will delete the saved web file after it is streamed to browser,
   'target' => '_blank',
   ```
3. [Batch Loading](http://demos.krajee.com/export-demo#batch-loading)

   ```
   'batchSize' => 10,
   'target' => '_blank',
   ```

Comment: I try this `echo ExportMenu::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => $gridColumns,
  'stream' => false, // this will automatically save the file to a folder on web server
'streamAfterSave' => true, // this will stream the file to browser after its saved on the web folder 
'deleteAfterSave' => true, // this will delete the saved web file after it is streamed to browser,
'target' => '_blank',
  ])
    ?>` but still 504

Comment: As I said: not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

try increase the max_execution_time

```
 <?php
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 3600); //3600 seconds = 60 minutes
       $gridColumns = [
       'order_number',
  [
```

Comment: didnt help. there is only 700 string. when there is like 200 all good.

Comment: update your question and add the action where you prepare the dataProvider for the export View  .. please

Comment: added action to question

Comment: How many  rows you  thinks should be exported?  .. and how many are effectively exported ?

Comment: what do you mean in your previous comment when you  write 'there is only 700 string. when there is like 200 all good'?    you get 700  rows instead fo 1000?

Comment: I mean: when 200 - all good download. now 700 - and there is 504 error. And I think there will be no more than 1000 rows at the same time

Comment: The Error 504 gateway time-out .. is showed  after  how many minutes?   is the time-out time according with you max_execution_time  setting?

Comment: this mean that the max_execution_time is not changed ..  try inspect the php.ini for this  .  should be 60 ..